# Conversion of graphs from TGF to d3.js

Tags: d3.js, graph-visualization, graphml

My current workflow is starting with graphs in [TGF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Graph_Format), reading them in with [yED](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and using yED to output them to some image format. I would rather have d3.js output.

Any tool out there (preferably a Ruby gem) that takes graphs in TGF format and outputs them in d3.js? Bonus points if it handles digraphs.

Comment: [There's a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/tgf) for reading & writing TGF files, which should get you some of the way there.

Comment: The tgf gem has no d3 writer. I'll probably have to roll my own.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools for this. The closest is probably [dagre](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre), which allows you to render graphviz graphs with D3.

Comment: Nice. You could easily extend this with a TGF grammar. Also, quite easy to use the Dagre pretty JS notation: https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre/blob/master/demo/state-graph-js.html

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to the tables of non-isomorphic semigroups from 2-10 split out by idempotents would you? :) http://4c.ucc.ie/~larsko/papers/cp-semigroups.pdf

Comment: It's all in the references of that paper :)

Comment: I found the non-isomorphic idempotent tables for 10 and 9. I can probably just calculate 2-7 on my laptop. 8 is still elusive though.